# Plotly Button Click Event not working

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am alien to javascript so pardon me for any naive mistake you find (though that's what I am looking for).

I tried to replicate the code provided for testing the button click event for plotly, but it's not getting fired.

Link from which code is imported:

https://plot.ly/javascript/custom-buttons/#bind-button-events-to-plotlyjs-charts

The way I used it in my html file to test it is shown in the image attached. It works well in code snippet, but due to some mistake of mine in using the javascript in the same page, I am not able to get in work.

Assistance highly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Figured it out...some how the cdn link to jquery wasn't working. Got a lesson: Never rely on the external, keep a local copy of all libraries and call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cdn link to jquery wasn't working.

Never rely on the external, keep a local copy of all libraries and call them